# Enable draggableColumns on datatable except some columns

Tags: primefaces, datatable

Is there any option to disable **draggable** options for some columns in a datatable ? 
I was building an applications in which i wanted the colums to be draggable but column like ID, name should be non-draggable.

I've enabled draggable using **draggableColumns="true** in **< DataTable > tag**. 
but it enables column re-ordering for all colums.

So is there any way i can disable this for some particular columns ?